# Origine de "gross malheur"

Tags: étymologie, allemand

D'où vient réellement l'expression humoristique "gross malheur" (ou "groß Malheur") ?

Références bienvenues.

Si je me trompe pas, cette expression (rare) est parfois utilisée pour ironiser sur un "first world problem" personnel.

Comment: Il me semble l'avoir entendu pour la première fois dans la bouche de Gérard Jugnot, peut-être dans un ses sketchs ou un de ses films. Désolé pour les références - Origine possible : la défaite allemande en 44 rendant goguenard les survivants des territoires occupés.

Comment: @cl-r *Papy fait de la résistance* si je ne m'abuse. A revoir pour confirmer et rigoler un peu... :)

Comment: La réplique se trouve aussi dans _Le Viager_ : « La guerre de Cent Ans ? Ach, gross malheur... »

Answer (score 10, accepted):

L'expression « Groß [Malheur](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Malheur) » (en français *grand malheur*) était employée en allemand avant d'être employée en français. Elle a été introduite en France à l'occasion de l'occupation d'une partie de la France pendant la 
[guerre franco allemande de 1870](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guerre_de_70).

Elle est citée par exemple dans les *[Essais sur l'Allemagne impériale](http://books.google.fr/books?id=LBdLAAAAMAAJ&q=%22gross%20malheur%22&dq=%22gross%20malheur%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=SOGBT_7PEoqU8gPbtuyEBg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA)* d'[Ernest Lavisse](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Lavisse) (1888): « Ah ! la guerre, disaient-ils à l'arrivée, en déposant leur sac ! Gross malheur, la guerre ! »

Depuis elle est très souvent employée avec une nuance ironique anti-allemande, en particulier dans des films comiques.

Comment: Merci ! "était employée en allemand": Intéressant mais d'où vient cette information ?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul : la plus [ancienne référence](http://www.google.fr/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=fr&q=Gro%C3%9F+Malheur+&btnG=#q=%22Gro%C3%9F+Malheur%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=OKKCT-WBB8vu8QOmotCsBg&ved=0CBwQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min%3A31%2F12%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A31%2F12%2F1830&tbm=bks&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=820bcff63af7fa04&biw=1920&bih=883) trouvée dans  google books date de 1822.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul : On peut voir qu'[en 1870](http://www.google.fr/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=fr&q=Gro%C3%9F+Malheur+&btnG=#q=%22Gro%C3%9F+Malheur%22&hl=fr&tbs=cdr:1,cd_max:1870&tbm=bks&ei=lqOCT86kEeil0QXd2tTzBg&start=0&sa=N&fp=1&biw=1920&bih=883&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&cad=b) les références sont relativement nombreuses.

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! Intéressant de voir aussi cette forme (ancienne?) avec apostrophe: groß' Malheur